# why won't f:selectItems allow me to add another value? JBOSS/JSF

Tags: java, jsf, el

I have the following code:

```
<ui:repeat var="_shipment"
value="#{_order.orderShipmentList}">
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{_shipment.shipmentMethodCode.id}">
    <f:selectItems id="selectShipList"
        value="#{consoleContext.shipmentMethods}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the f:selectItems value attribute I want to add #{_shipment.shipmentMethodCode.id} - #{consoleContext.shipmentMethods}

SO it would read 1 - Standard Shipping

But I get an error:
Expected a child component type of UISelectItem/UISelectItems for component type javax.faces.SelectOne(j_id58). Found java.lang.String.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute should point to a collection of Javabeans or `SelectItem` objects, not to strings.

If you don't/can't change it in the Javabean or `SelectItem` side, then you need the to use `itemLabel` attribute instead.

```xml
<f:selectItems id="selectShipList" value="#{consoleContext.shipmentMethods}" var="shipmentMethod" 
    itemValue="#{shipmentMethod.id}" itemLabel="#{shipmentMethod.id} - #{shipmentMethod.name}" />
```